# How to save loop data in the database in php and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm developing a form, which has got some fields and whose data gets saved in the sql server database.
I'm able to save the data to the database for the rest of the form, however I'm stuck at a button which upon clicking shows more fileds. It's a loop which runs five times, so the user will have an option of adding details of their mentors for five times. I'm not sure how to save the data of the loop in the database.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="container" >
        <form class="cmxform" action ='functions/processform.php' id="Form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id="FormResult1" class="hide" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <div id="resultFormContent1"></div>
            </div>
<h1>Contact Information</h1>                
                <div class="form-row">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="fName">First Name </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fName" name="fName" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="lName">Last Name </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lName" name="lName" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="uEmail">University Email </label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="uEmail" name="uEmail" required>
                </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id=new_site></div>
   
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  onClick="addSite()">Add Mentor</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  onClick="removeSite()">Remove Mentor</button>
            <input type="hidden" value="1" id="total_sites">
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-primary" id="registerSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
  <script> 
       function addSite() {
    
       var new_total_sites = parseInt($('#total_sites').val()) + 1;
     if ($('#total_sites').val() >= 4) {
     $('button:contains("Add Mentor")').prop('disabled', true);
   }
   
   var new_label= "<label id='new_label9_" + new_total_sites
                + "'><h1>Mentor#"+ new_total_sites +"</h1></label><br>";
   var new_site_label = "<label id='new_label1_" + new_total_sites
                + "'>Length of Time in Research: </label>";
   var new_site_input = "<input id='new_site_"
                + new_total_sites
                + "' type='text' class='form-control col-md-12' list='sites' name='site[]'></br>";
   var new_slot_label = "<label id='new_label2_" + new_total_sites
                + "'>Research Institution</label>";
   var new_slot_input = "<input class='form-control col-md-12' id='new_slot_"
                + new_total_sites + "' name='slots[]'></br>";
  var new_research_label = "<label id='new_label3_" + new_total_sites
                + "'>Research Mentor</label>";
   var new_research_input = "<input class='form-control' id='new_research_"
                + new_total_sites + "' name='slots[]'></br>";
   var new_form_group_label= "<label id='new_label4_" + new_total_sites
                + "'>Type of Research</label><br>";
   var new_basic_label = "<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox1" + new_total_sites +"' value='basic'><label for='basic' id='basic"+ new_total_sites +"'>Basic</label></br>";
   var new_clinical_label = "<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox2" + new_total_sites +"' value='clinical'><label for='clinical' id='clinical"+ new_total_sites +"'>Clinical</label></br></div>";
   var new_form_label= "<label id='new_label5_" + new_total_sites
                + "'><h1>Mentor's Contact Information</h1></label>";
   var new_mentor_label = "<label id='new_label6_" + new_total_sites
                + "'>Mentor's Phone</label>";
   var new_mentor_input = "<input class='form-control' id='new_mentor_"
                + new_total_sites + "' name='slots[]'></br>";
   var new_mentoremail_label ="<label id='new_label7_" + new_total_sites
                + "'>Mentor's Email</label>";
    var new_mentoremail_input = "<input class='form-control' id='new_mentoremail_"
                + new_total_sites + "' name='slots[]'></br>";
    var new_describeresearch_label = "<label id='new_label8_" + new_total_sites
                + "'>Describe your research</label></div>";
    var new_describeresearch_input = "<input class='form-control' id='new_describeresearch_"
                + new_total_sites + "' name='slots[]'></br>";

   $('#new_site').append(new_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_site_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_site_input);
   $('#new_site').append(new_slot_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_slot_input);
   $('#new_site').append(new_research_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_research_input);
   $('#new_site').append(new_form_group_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_basic_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_clinical_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_form_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_mentor_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_mentor_input);
   $('#new_site').append(new_mentoremail_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_mentoremail_input);
   $('#new_site').append(new_describeresearch_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_describeresearch_input);
   
   

   $('#total_sites').val(new_total_sites)
    }


 function removeSite() {
   var last_total_site = $('#total_sites').val();
   if (last_total_site > 1) {
         $('#new_label9_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label1_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_site_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label2_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_slot_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label3_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_research_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label4_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#basic' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#clinical' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#checkbox1' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#checkbox2' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label5_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label6_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_mentor_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label7_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_mentoremail_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label8_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_describeresearch_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         
        $('#total_sites').val(last_total_site - 1);
   }
 }

   </script>
</body>

</html>
```

processform.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
 require_once 'db-connect.php';
 require_once 'email.php';
 if(isset($_POST['pEmail'])){
 $fName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "fName") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fName') : null;
 $lName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "lName")? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lName') : null;
 $uEmail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "uEmail")? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'uEmail') : null;
 $conn = DB::databaseConnection();
 $conn->beginTransaction();
 $sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.form ( FirstName,LastName,universityemail)VALUES 
            ( :fName,:lName,universityemail)
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':fName', $fName);
$stmt->bindParam(':lName', $lName);
  $stmt->bindParam(':universityemail', $uEmail);
  if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $conn->commit();
   if (Form::mailer($fName, $lName,$uEmail))) {
   echo 
        '<script >
            alert("Thank you for registration.");
            window.location = "www.google.com/";
        </script>';
    
        return true;
    } else {
        $conn->rollback();
        echo '
        <script>
            alert("Error, please try submitting again. Error code 1");
            window.history.back();
        </script>';
        return false;
    }
  }
  }
```

The rest of the fields gets saved in the database, I'm just not sure how to save the loop data in the same way.

Comment: What's the database schema for these looped fields? Is the table normalized with one record per row, or will all 5 be put in the same record?

Comment: Each fields has a separate column, so there are 7 columns for each loop. 35 in total.

Comment: What have you tried in saving these fields?

Comment: How do you submit your form?

Comment: Yes, sorry the form is too long hence posted some part of it. I'll edit the code above